# How to filter multiple options/strings of an array in one filter?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a multiple selection dropdown where users can filter accordingly, e.g. if `Live` and `Schedule`is selected, only the results that have these two criteria should appear.

[image]

This is my current filtering function for the multi-select dropdown:

**Filtering function & handleChange**

```
 const displayBulletins = bulletins
    .filter((bulletin) => {
        if (optionSelected === '') {
            return bulletin
        } else if (bulletin.liveStatus.toLowerCase().includes(optionSelected.map(item => item.value))) {
            return bulletin
        }
        return false
    })

const handleChange = selected => {
        setOptionSelected(selected)
        console.log(selected, '--optionsSelected')
        console.log(selected.map(item => item.value), '--mappedOptionsSelected')
    };
```

[image]

My current issue is that, if I have only `selected 1 of the live status` options, the filtering works, but if I selected more than one option, it doesn't work and filters out nothing instead, so what I'm trying to achieve here is to make it work for multiple selections such as `["live", "schedule"]` in this case or for all 3 cases.

Here's my code sandbox for reference:

[image: Edit festive-pare-vhisn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter's callback should look something like this:

```
filter((bulletin) => {
  if (optionSelected.length === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return optionSelected
      .map((item) => item.value)
      .includes(bulletin.liveStatus.toLowerCase());
  }
})
```

because you have to check if the `optionSelected` array has the `liveStatus` but not the other way around.

Here's the updated CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit zealous-star-exzj2]

BTW defining function components in the body of a function component causes unnecessary rerenders. In the case of `react-select` it causes focus issues, this is why the dropdown is not closing when clicked outside.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, by ```defining function components in the body of a function component``` do you mean by how I'm putting ```react-select``` in ```DisplayBulletinSelect``` and using it in ```Bulletins```? I'm still relatively new to ReactJS so I still don't really know what causes these unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: @Lance I'm referring to the function components like `Option`, `ValueContainer`, `MultiValue` etc. These should be defined outside `Bulletins`.

Comment: I see, by defining them outside ```Bulletins``` you meant by doing like this right? You can check my latest code sandbox here if you don't mind:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-pare-vhisn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/Bulletin/Bulletins.js)

Comment: @Lance Yes, that looks good. You can see that the dropdown got fixed.

Comment: @Lance Improved the filter callback as we can directly return the boolean. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks a lot for letting me know about this, you've taught me a lot of new things today!

Comment: What's the difference between directly returning the boolean and returning the ```bulletin``` array?

Comment: @Lance It works both ways because `bulletin` is a truthy value. Returning the returned value of includes just makes the callback a bit concise.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem here is that `optionsSelected` is an array and `bulletin.liveStatus` is an array, so you need to look if `liveStatus` is in the `optionsSelected` array**

I modify with the following in the code sandbox and it worked.

Also, ***don't forget to add a Fragment with a key*** instead <> to allow React to perform well in re-rendering virtual DOM.

If you want to display all bulletins if no option is selected, instead of return `false` you should return `true`

```
  const displayBulletins = bulletins
    .filter((bulletin) => {
      if (optionSelected === []) {
        return bulletin;
      } else if (
        optionSelected
          .map((item) => item.value)
          .includes(bulletin.liveStatus.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return bulletin;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .map((bulletin) => {
      return (
        <Fragment key={bulletin.bbID}>
          <BulletinList
            bulletin={bulletin}
            onDelete={onDelete}
          />
        </Fragment>
      );
    });
```

Comment: "If you want to display all bulletins if no option is selected, instead of return false you should return true" - No, the condition in the first `if` will always be false as you're comparing with a new array `[]` every time.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation and for the ```Fragment``` with key for better re-rendering performance tip as well.